# Jquery autocomplete input text created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, autocomplete

I'm trying to do a code in order that users can add an unlimited numbers of occupations via a "+" button which create input text occupation[]. But when the new input text is created, he cannot be autocomplete like the others natives input (not created dynamically).

**So how to add correctly new input text for permit autocompletion of all the input ?**

Here is my Jquery code for autocomplete:

```
    $('input[name="occupation[]"]').on("keyup", function(){
    var occup = $(this).val();
    var currentElement = $(this);       
    if(occup != ""){ 
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "page_geneoccup.php",
            data: {"occup":occup},
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(responseData){
                var liste_occup=responseData; 
                $(currentElement).autocomplete({
                    source: liste_occup
                }); 
                return;
            },
            error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrow){
                console.log("Error: " + XMLHttpRequest.status + errorThrow );
                return;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

PS: Sorry for my english...

Best regards

---

My new code but, functioning for the first input and not for the others:

```
   <html lang="fr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />         
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>


    var oAutoCompleteElements = {
    addInputEvents:function(newInputs){
        var r_newInputs = $(newInputs);
        $(newInputs).each(function(i, oInput){
            $(oInput).off();
            $(oInput).on('keyup',function(){
                var occup = $(oInput).val();
                if(occup){
                $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "page_geneoccup.php",
                data: {"occup":occup},
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function(responseData){
                    var liste_occup=responseData; 
                    $(oInput).autocomplete({
                        source: liste_occup
                    }); 
                    return;
                },
                error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrow){
                    console.log("Error: " + XMLHttpRequest.status + errorThrow );
                    return;
                }
            });
                }
            });
        });
    },
    addButtonEvents:function(){
        $('#addNewInput').on('click',function(){
            oAutoCompleteElements.addNewInput();
        });
    },
    addNewInput:function(){
        newInput ='<input type="text" name="occupation[]"/>';
        $('#occupationsContainer').append(newInput);
          oAutoCompleteElements.addInputEvents($('input[name="occupation[]"]:last'));
    },
    init:function(){
       this.addButtonEvents();
       this.addInputEvents($('input[name="occupation[]"]'));
    }
};

$(function(){
    oAutoCompleteElements.init();
});


var counter = 1;
function addInput()
{
          var target        = document.getElementById('occupationsContainer');
          var newdiv        = document.createElement('div');
          var newdivname    = 'Div' + counter;
          newdiv.setAttribute('id',newdivname);
          content = newdiv.innerHTML;
          content +='<input name="occupation[]">';
          content +='<a id="AccountDelete" href="#" onclick="removeInput(\'' + newdivname + '\');">[Supprimer cet enfant]</a><br><br><hr><br><br>';
          newdiv.innerHTML = content;
          target.appendChild(newdiv);
          counter++;
}

function removeInput(idInput)
{
    var elmt = document.getElementById(idInput);
    elmt.parentNode.removeChild(elmt);
}   
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>



<div  id="occupationsContainer">
<input name="occupation[]">
<input type="button"  id="addNewButton" value="add" onclick="addInput();">
</div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

A last idea in order to definitely solve this problem ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You could make a container (a form, div, whatever) for all the inputs and use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events). This would allow you to not create event listeners for each of the inputs.

Your example code would then be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    var addNewInput = function() {
      $('#occupationsContainer').append('<input name="occupation[]" />');
    }

    /* delete last input from occupationsContainer, 
       but make sure it's not the first one */
    var deleteInput = function() {
      $('#occupationsContainer>input').not(':first').remove(':last');
    }

    /* this listens for keyup event on any input in the element
       with id occcupationsContainer */
    $('#occupationsContainer').on("keyup", "input", function() {
      var occup = $(this).val();
      var currentElement = $(this);
      if (occup != "") {
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "page_geneoccup.php",
          data: {
            "occup": occup
          },
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(responseData) {
            var liste_occup = responseData;
            $(currentElement).autocomplete({
              source: liste_occup
            });
            return;
          },
          error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrow) {
            console.log("Error: " + XMLHttpRequest.status + errorThrow);
            return;
          }
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="addBtn" onclick="addNewInput()">Add</button>
  <button id="removeBtn" onclick="deleteInput()">Remove</button>
  <div id="occupationsContainer">
    <input name="occupation[]" />
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for this answer, but with this method, how are added the new input text ?

Comment: see the edited version, also a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AIoYaKpHGY43vO5V6A0v?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

the new element is not part of the DOM at the moment you call DOM ready, and will not be part of the array you create in $('input[name="occupation[]"]');

You should add the element to the array, either by reinitiating the function you use to add the autocompleter to your elements.

I removed this part because it was getting to freaking long.

In your body you only need an element containing your inputs with 
id="occupationsContainer" 
and a button with 
id="addNewButton"

and that should do what you want ;)

final solution:

Also remove the button from the occupationsContainer element,And add it outside of those brackets, this will make sure that element is always beneath the inputs.

---

```
var oAutoCompleteElements = {
    counter:1,
    addInputEvents:function(newInputs){
       var r_newInputs = $(newInputs);
       $(newInputs).each(function(i, oInput){
           $(oInput).off();
           $(oInput).on('keyup',function(){
              var occup = $(oInput).val();
              if(occup){
                  console.log('a call to your autocompleter list');
              }
          });

         //add events to the new deleteButton
         var deleteInput = $(oInput).parent().find('.deleteInput');
         $(deleteInput).each(function(i, oDelete){
              $(oDelete).on('click',function(){
                  oAutoCompleteElements.removeInput($(oInput).parent());
              });
          });
       });
    },
    //add events to the add button,
    addButtonEvents:function(){
        $('#addNewInput').on('click',function(){
            oAutoCompleteElements.addNewInput();
        });
    },
    //add a new input
    addNewInput:function(){
        newInput ='<div id="Div' + oAutoCompleteElements.counter + '"><input    type="text" name="occupation[]"/><a class="deleteInput">[Supprimer cet enfant]</a></div>';
         oAutoCompleteElements.counter ++ ;
         $('#occupationsContainer').append(newInput);

         oAutoCompleteElements.addInputEvents($('input[name="occupation[]"]:last'));
    },
    //remove an input
    removeInput:function(oInput_container){
       $(oInput_container).remove();
       oAutoCompleteElements.counter --;
    },
    init:function(){
       this.addButtonEvents();
       this.addInputEvents($('input[name="occupation[]"]'));
    }
};

$(function(){
    oAutoCompleteElements.init();
});
```

Comment: Thank you but how can I call this functions ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
<html lang="fr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />         
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>


    var oAutoCompleteElements = {
    addInputEvents:function(newInputs){
        var r_newInputs = $(newInputs);
        $(newInputs).each(function(i, oInput){
            $(oInput).off();
            $(oInput).on('keyup',function(){
                var occup = $(oInput).val();
                if(occup){
                $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "page_geneoccup.php",
                data: {"occup":occup},
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function(responseData){
                    var liste_occup=responseData; 
                    $(oInput).autocomplete({
                        source: liste_occup
                    }); 
                    return;
                },
                error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrow){
                    console.log("Error: " + XMLHttpRequest.status + errorThrow );
                    return;
                }
            });
                }
            });
        });
    },
    addButtonEvents:function(){
        $('#addNewInput').on('click',function(){
            oAutoCompleteElements.addNewInput();
        });
    },
    addNewInput:function(){
        newInput ='<input type="text" name="occupation[]"/>';
        $('#occupationsContainer').append(newInput);
          oAutoCompleteElements.addInputEvents($('input[name="occupation[]"]:last'));
    },
    init:function(){
       this.addButtonEvents();
       this.addInputEvents($('input[name="occupation[]"]'));
    }
};

$(function(){
    oAutoCompleteElements.init();
});



    </script>

    </head>
    <body>



<div  id="occupationsContainer">
<input name="occupation[]">
<input type="button"  id="addNewInput" value="add">
</div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Thank you a lot for your help.